# Upload text to an asp.net generic handler in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, webrequest

How can I upload text written by the user to an asp.net generic handler? the text is pretty lengthy.

Comment: Pretty lengthy?  What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language. the file is huge and I cannot just pass as a QueryString.

Comment: Tried with little success, that is why I asked the question, I thought I used the wrong method. I am either having problem sending or receiving the date in the handler.

Comment: "the file is huge"  What does that mean?

Comment: Well, you can using POST, as stated above. Can you tell us what part works and what part does not? Any error code or even an error message? Maybe even show us (part of) your JavaScript and/or handler...

Comment: I tried this one from the javascript side:
"$.post("HHelper.ashx?cmnd=compile", {data: file}, function(data){
alert(data);
});"
And I received the data using "context.Request["file"]". There are no errors, but the data doesn't transfer at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some jQuery code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#button-id-to-submit-info-to-the-handler').on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        //Wrap your msg in some fashion
        //in case you want to end other things
        //to your handler in the future
        var $xml = $('<root />')
            .append($('<msg />', { 
                text: escape($('#id-of-your-textarea-that-has-the-text').val()) 
            }
        ));

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/path/to-your/handler.ashx',
            data: $('<nothing />').append($xml).html(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('body').prepend($('<div />', { text: $(data).find('responsetext').text() }));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And in your handler:

```cs
public class YourHandler : IHttpHandler
{
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
   {
       //Response with XML
       //Build a response template
       ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
       String rspBody = @"<?xml version=\""1.0\"" encoding=\""utf-8\"" standalone=\""yes\""?>
<root>
    <responsetext>{0}</responsetext>
</root>";

      //Get the xml document created via jquery
      //and load it into an XmlDocument
      XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
      using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ctx.Request.InputStream))
      {
         String xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
         xDoc.LoadXml(xml);
      }

      //Find your <msg> node and decode the text
      XmlNode msg = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/msg");
      String msgText = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(msg.InnerXml);
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(msgText))
      {
          //Success!!
          //Do whatever you plan on doing with this
          //and send a success response back
          ctx.Response.Write(String.Format(rspBody, "SUCCESS"));
      }
      else
      {
          ctx.Response.Write(String.Format(rspBody, "FAIL: msgText was Empty!"));
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code from your comment (thanks for sharing), it seems like the parameter containing your text is called `data` in your JavaScript and you are looking for `file` in your handler.

Try: `context.Request.Form["data"]` in your handler.

Comment: I made a mistake in the comment, anyway thanks. cmd.prompt gave an answer.